# Why don't I see fmt logs in my terminal when running go app locally?

Tags: go, fmt

I'm trying to debug my golang app. Currently, I have an API request that isn't working which has this line of code:
`fmt.Errorf("Object(%q).CopierFrom(%q).Run: %v", dstName, object, err)`

How can I view the output of this error log? And if it's not possible what are some other ways to debug in go? (runtime invocation would be nice)

Comment: If you want to log an error, you have to log it.  `fmt.Errorf` just creates an error object.  An error has no output.

Comment: If you'll update your question with some actual code, it will be easier to provide a concrete suggestion.  But maybe you want to call `fmt.Printf` or `log.Error` or something like that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fmt.Errorf()` creates an error object. but not print.[doc](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Errorf)

If you're just trying to print the message to stdout:
[run](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#example-Errorf)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    const name, id = "bueller", 17
    err := fmt.Errorf("user %q (id %d) not found", name, id)
    fmt.Println(err.Error())

}
```

out:

```
user "bueller" (id 17) not found
```

if you want debug golang code, I recommend use log packages for example:
[zerolog](https://github.com/rs/zerolog)

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"

    "github.com/rs/zerolog"
    "github.com/rs/zerolog/log"
)

func main() {
    // UNIX Time is faster and smaller than most timestamps
    zerolog.TimeFieldFormat = zerolog.TimeFormatUnix

    err := errors.New("seems we have an error here")
    log.Error().Err(err).Msg("this is an error")
}
```

out:

```
{"level":"error","error":"seems we have an error here","time":1640795128,"message":"this is an error"}
```

Answer (score 2):

`fmt.Errorf` creates an `error` object; it does not print.

From the docs for [`fmt.Errorf`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#example-Errorf):

```
func Errorf(format string, a ...interface{}) error
```

If you're just trying to print the message to stdout:

```
fmt.Printf("Object(%q).CopierFrom(%q).Run: %v\n", dstName, object, err)
```

If you want to write to an error log, I recommend looking at the [`log`](https://pkg.go.dev/log) package. For example, if you were looking to write to stderr:

```
logger := log.New(os.Stderr, "my-app", 0)
logger.Printf("Object(%q).CopierFrom(%q).Run: %v", dstName, object, err)
```

Answer (score 1):

`fmt.Errorf` creates an error - ideal for function returns - but it's not implicitly logged.

If you want to log an error simply:

```
log.Printf("api X: error %v", err)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to read the function signature and comments before you use any functions.

```golang
// Errorf formats according to a format specifier and returns the string as a
// value that satisfies error.
//
// If the format specifier includes a %w verb with an error operand,
// the returned error will implement an Unwrap method returning the operand. It is
// invalid to include more than one %w verb or to supply it with an operand
// that does not implement the error interface. The %w verb is otherwise
// a synonym for %v.
func Errorf(format string, a ...interface{}) error
```